# How to solve race condition of two writers using immutable objects

Tags: java, multithreading

I was thinking about how to solve race condition between two threads which tries to write to the same variable using immutable objects and without helping any keywords such as synchronize(lock)/volatile in java.

But I couldn't figure it out, is it possible to solve this problem with such solution at all?

```
public class Test {
    private static IAmSoImmutable iAmSoImmutable;

    private static final Runnable increment1000Times = () -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            iAmSoImmutable.increment();
        }
    };

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            iAmSoImmutable = new IAmSoImmutable(0);

            Thread t1 = new Thread(increment1000Times);
            Thread t2 = new Thread(increment1000Times);

            t1.start();
            t2.start();

            t1.join();
            t2.join();

            // Prints a different result every time -- why? :
            System.out.println(iAmSoImmutable.value);
        }
    }

    public static class IAmSoImmutable {
        private int value;

        public IAmSoImmutable(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public IAmSoImmutable increment() {
            return new IAmSoImmutable(++value);
        }
    }
```

If you run this code you'll get different answers every time, which mean a race condition is happening.

Comment: No, because the method returns a new object with the new value, and doesn't change the existing object. So the object is still immutable, because its state doesn't change.

Comment: I don't think so! how about getAndIncrement in Atomics?

Comment: @dunni How it doesn't change, if `++value` changes value of object's variable `value`?

Comment: @austinpowers they are mutable, but thread-safe.

Comment: The line `return new IAmSoImmutable(++value)` should be `return new IAmSoImmutable(1+value)`

Comment: BTW `increment()` is nonsense, because its result (new object) is never used

Comment: @Andremoniy it is bcoz of immutability I suppose.

Comment: Your class is weird, a mix of immutability and builder design pattern. Because it IS immutable does not mean you're using it correctly. What are you doing with the new object returned by your methods?

Comment: Immutability enforses thread-safety because state of object never changes (at leash should not) during all its life, thus such objects can be shared safely. But working with thread-safe objects in thread-unsafe manner (as you do) leads to thread-unsafe code.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou thats why I want to know what is the correct way of using immutables

Comment: @austinpowers correct way will depend on what you exactly need.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou I want to get 2000 for all iteration in my main method without helping atomics/volatile/locks

Comment: @austinpowers then create two different local variables in each thread, increment them separately and at the end sum the results. With one shared variable you won't achieve proper result without synchronization.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou its another way of thinking but I want to simulate a condition which I can't do such and I have to use one variable for solving it. I am wondering how is it possible in functional languages to solve similar problems using immutability but not in java!?

Comment: @austinpowers even if you make `ImSoImmutable` truly immutable, race conditions will occur between reading and re-writing the reference to shared instance representing the "current" state. So synchronization would be still required.

Comment: Just using the word "immutable" in a class name does not make it immutable.  The `value` field of IASI is mutable, and in fact mutated by `increment()`.  See Effective Java item "Favor immutability" for a recipe for constructing an immutable class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fundamental problem here is that you've misunderstood what "immutability" means.

"Immutability" means — no writes. Values are created, but are never modified.

Immutability ensures that there are no race conditions, because race conditions are always caused by writes: either two threads performing writes that aren't consistent with each other, or one thread performing writes and another thread performing reads that give inconsistent results, or similar.

(Caveat: even an immutable object is effectively mutable during construction — Java creates the object, then populates its fields — so in addition to being immutable in general, you need to use the `final` keyword appropriately and take care with what you do in the constructor. But, those are minor details.)

With that understanding, we can go back to your initial sentence:

> I was thinking about how to solve race condition between two threads which tries to write to the same variable using immutable objects and without helping any keywords such as synchronize(lock)/volatile in java.

The problem here is that you actually *aren't* using immutable objects: your entire goal is to perform writes, and the entire concept of immutability is that no writes happen. These are not compatible.

That said, immutability certainly has its place. You can have immutable `IAmSoImmutable` objects, with the only writes being that you swap these objects out for each other. That helps simplify the problem, by reducing the scope of writes that you have to worry about: there's only one kind of write. But even that one kind of write will require synchronization.

The best approach here is probably to use an `AtomicReference<IAmSoImmutable>`. This provides a non-blocking way to swap out your `IAmSoImmutable`-s, while guaranteeing that no write gets silently dropped.

(In fact, in the special case that your value is just an integer, the JDK provides `AtomicInteger` that handles the necessary compare-and-swap loops and so on for threadsafe incrementation.)

Comment: Then how to implement a global state in pure func language? For example if I need count global users, in Java AtomicLong could be the answer, if an immutable object is used, each call to count returns a complete new object, won't there be a race condition? multi threads call on the same value+1?

Comment: @PeiSongXiong: Pure functional languages don't usually have a concept of "global state", *per se*. If you're interested in how that works, I recommend trying out such a language. Haskell is a popular one; I've also heard some good things about Clean.

Answer (score 5):

You can not solve race condition without using any of existence synchronisation (or volatile) techniques. That what they were designed for. If it would be possible there would be no need of them.

More particularly your code seems to be broken. This method:

```
public IAmSoImmutable increment() {
            return new IAmSoImmutable(++value);
}
```

is nonsense for two reasons:

1) It makes broken immutability of class, because it changes object's variable `value`.

2) Its result - new instance of class `IAmSoImmutable` - is never used.

Comment: Immutable object means not changing the state of any variables right? thats why I have to create another new object out of my old object because the old value has changed.

Comment: @austinpowers auto incrementing changes the value of `value` so the contract is broken.

Comment: Re: "You can not solve race condition without using any of existence synchronisation (or volatile) techniques": True, but you can *avoid* race conditions by using immutable objects and `final`. The OP seems to have read about that, but is having difficulty translating that idea into practice. (But +1 for the rest of your answer.)

Comment: @austinpowers That is still not an immutable, so stop with the immutable argument for thread safety.

Comment: @austinpowers as I wrote in commentaries above, you have to write this method as `return new IAmSoImmutable(1+value)`, but it also nonsense because you don't use its result

Comment: @ruakh yeah, but would you agree with me, that it isn't quite clear from first sentence of the question? It looks like he really want to avoid race conditions without using sync utils.

Comment: @austinpowers As I wrote twice it will not work in your case because of wrong usage of the method and wrong architecture in whole. But it will fix the contract of immutability at least.

Comment: @austinpowers Did he give a solution? I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the problems are resolved by :

1. Avoiding the change of `IAmSoImmutable.value`
2. Reassigning the new object created within `increment()` back into the `iAmSoImmutable` reference.

There still are pieces of your code that are not atomic and that needs a sort of synchronization.

---

A solution would be to use a synchronized method of course

```
public synchronized static void increment() {
    iAmSoImmutable = iAmSoImmutable.increment();
}
```

---

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        increment();
    }
});

Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        increment();
    }
});
```